# mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on . .

Tags: automount

I am trying to auto mount 2 hard drives on a newly setup desktop.

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 ran the updates and then immediately went to the Disk GUI in Ubuntu and set the auto mount on the ext4 partitions to auto mount.

I then reboot and the system then tells me just before it gets to the desktop that there was a problem mounting a drive and I can skip or go to recovery.  I will skip and the 2nd hard drive will give the same message and then I skip.

After which I get to the desktop and then I cannot access the drives.  When it tries to mount I will get an error that will read in essence

> mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper gram, or other error n some cases useful info is found in syslog - try  dmesg | tail  or so".

I don't have a screen shot of the message but this is what it says when I do a mount -a from the terminal.  Once I remove the auto mount setting I can then mount the drives by clicking on them in the file manager window.

I am a newbie to Linux and Ubuntu so I am at a loss . . .

Comment: have you tried to use fstab? try to insert a line like `UUID=your-uuid       /home/username/whereever/you/want  auto user,rw,nodev 0  0` into your `/etc/fstab`

Comment: this is what the Disk GUI does, adds a statement to the fstab with that format.

Comment: Please post the contents of your `/etc/fstab`. Also, what do you mean by "automount"? That's a different thing altogether. I think you mean mounting by default.